# What does "set in" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

Granpa liked to have some in his jug for occasional liquorin' and **settin' in** before company. (in The Education of Little Tree)

Bold part, What does "set in" mean here?
It's not even in the dictionary.

Comment: At a guess, it means _getting himself ready_ for the company, i.e. getting a little drunk so that he can better tolerate bothersome guests.

Comment: Or it could be colloquial for, "settling in." I.E., have a "sit down" with company and a jug of moonshine (made by moonlight, so the "revenuers", tax authority, doesn't see an illegal still smoking away in daylight).

Comment: Thanks all of you for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To set" is Appalachian(1) slang directly translated as "to sit down" or "to settle" or "to rest." It specifically means to sit down or get off your feet AND to mentally slow down or stop thinking of so many things at once. Here are some examples of this:

- "Mama, here's a chair- set down and let me do the dishes."
- "I need to set for a moment."
- "Set yourself on that there stool and stop fretting."

In this passage, the narrator is saying that his grandfather wanted to rest and collect himself before company arrived, so he would have a drink and sit quietly for a while.

(1) Appalachia is a rural mountainous region of the northeast and central-east US. Due to the mountains, there are many isolated communities which developed a unique dialect, especially before modern TV, internet, etc. This is called Appalachian English or Mountain English.

---

(Note - you likely know this, but here's some [interesting information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asa_Earl_Carter) about the author of this book.)

Comment: Also still found in some parts of England. 'Set yourself down' may be used as a hospitable invitation to a visitor in some places.